# Python get a list of a file's group_id permissions in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, permissions

I was able to do this for Linux in a minute, but for the life of me I can't find an answer for Windows.

I tried `os.stat`, but from what I understand the module may not work properly with some Python and Windows versions.

I couldn't find any method in `win32net` where you can supply a file path and get info from it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

After research of internet i have found one solution.
(https://sites.google.com/site/hvanbelle/programming/python/python---win32security/python---win32security---list-permissions)

```
import os, sys
import win32security

dacl = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo (path,
win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
).GetSecurityDescriptorDacl ()

for n_ace in range (dacl.GetAceCount ()):
    ace = dacl.GetAce (n_ace)
    sid = ace[-1] 
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid (None, sid)
    

    print("%s \\%s " % (domain, name)
```

Comment: If this is not your content then please attribute it correcty by providing the link to the source. Adding some explanation would also be a nice touch.

Comment: Please see the link 
 (https://sites.google.com/site/hvanbelle/programming/python/python---win32security/python---win32security---list-permissions) i have update the code according to my need

Answer (score -1):

This seems to get the info that I want.

```
import win32net
import win32security

security_descriptor = win32security.GetFileSecurity("my\\path", win32security.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION)

win32security.LookupAccountSid(win32net.NetGetAnyDCName(), security_descriptor.GetSecurityDescriptorGroup())
```

Comment: That seems unlikely to be useful; the primary group is rarely used in Windows.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Trying to get the file's groups. Is there a better way?

Comment: That retrieves the name of the file's primary group, which is only relevant under unusual circumstances.  It doesn't affect who can access the file, for example.  ("The file's groups" is not a meaningful phrase in Windows, and I'm not familiar enough with Linux to sensibly guess at your intent.)

Comment: When you right click on a file and go to the security tab there's a list of different groups that show their permissions. I'm referring to that (says group names!).

Comment: That's the DACL.  It doesn't necessarily contain only groups, it can contain users and other security primitives, although as far as I can recall LookupAccountSid should work on all of them.  You'll want `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` and `GetSecurityDescriptorDacl` and then you'll have to enumerate the ACEs with something like `GetAce` or perhaps `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. That documentation gets me a bit confused at times :)

Comment: Using `GetAceCount` and `GetAce` will include inherited ACEs, unlike `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`. I suspect you want the inherited entries.