# How to check directory access attributes (permissions)?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to check access to the directory (permissions for groups) on Windows 8.1 / 10. The bottom line is that a situation is possible where all permissions or part of them are prohibited and, in this case, I do not want to throw *expection*, and even more so with *errno*.

It is necessary to understand in advance the function (s) that will show whether I will have `WinError` or `PermissionError` when reading/writing, for a specific group or all groups (`SYSTEM`, `Administrator`, etc.).

The standard `stat` library and `os.access()` did not give me the desired results. There are also options with changing permissions for the directory, but this may not always work, especially in `usermode`, which is why I try to do the verification.

I also tried to read the rights of the `ACL`, but nothing came of it because of inexperience.

Such conclusions were drawn from the following code (did I check it exactly like that? I don’t know.), And games with the directory security settings (I also changed the location of the directory to the `desktop`, `my documents`, `%appdata%` and other spaces intended for user data [Everything in `C:\Users\% USER_NAME%\`]. I thought it might be a mistake.), which always produced the same result (maybe sometimes slightly different, but this does not cancel the question).
The most important thing is that an `Exception` will be thrown if you try to do something with this directory that is not allowed by the rules, and execute in this way:

```py
import os
import stat

def access(path, flag): return os.access(path, flag)
def isExists(path): return access(path, os.F_OK)
def isReadable(path): return access(path, os.R_OK)
def isWritable(path): return access(path, os.W_OK)
def isExecuteable(path): return access(path, os.X_OK)

def mstat(path, followsymlink = 1):
    if isinstance(path, str):
        info = os.stat(path)
        if followsymlink and stat.S_ISLNK(info[stat.ST_MODE]):
            return(os.lstat(path))
        return(info)
    return(os.fstat(path))

def _mode(path): return(mstat(path)[stat.ST_MODE])

def mode(path):   return(stat.S_IMODE(_mode(path)))
def ifreg(path):  return(stat.S_ISREG(_mode(path)))
def ifdir(path):  return(stat.S_ISDIR(_mode(path)))
def ifchr(path):  return(stat.S_ISCHR(_mode(path)))
def ifblk(path):  return(stat.S_ISBLK(_mode(path)))
def iffifo(path): return(stat.S_ISFIFO(_mode(path)))
def iflnk(path):  return(stat.S_ISLNK(_mode(path)))
def ifsock(path): return(stat.S_ISSOCK(_mode(path)))

def is_suid(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISUID == stat.S_ISUID)
def is_sgid(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISGID == stat.S_ISGID)
def is_svtx(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISVTX == stat.S_ISVTX)
def is_read(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IREAD == stat.S_IREAD)
def is_write(path): return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWRITE == stat.S_IWRITE)
def is_exec(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IEXEC == stat.S_IEXEC)
def is_rwxu(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXU == stat.S_IRWXU)
def is_rusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRUSR == stat.S_IRUSR)
def is_wusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWUSR == stat.S_IWUSR)
def is_xusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXUSR == stat.S_IXUSR)
def is_rwxg(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXG == stat.S_IRWXG)
def is_rgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRGRP == stat.S_IRGRP)
def is_wgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWGRP == stat.S_IWGRP)
def is_xgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXGRP == stat.S_IXGRP)
def is_rwxo(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXO == stat.S_IRWXO)
def is_roth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IROTH == stat.S_IROTH)
def is_woth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWOTH == stat.S_IWOTH)
def is_xoth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXOTH == stat.S_IXOTH)

path = 'C:\\ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_SAMPLE'

print(f'''
    mode    = {mode(path)}
    ifreg   = {ifreg(path)}
    ifdir   = {ifdir(path)}
    ifchr   = {ifchr(path)}
    ifblk   = {ifblk(path)}
    iffifo  = {iffifo(path)}
    iflnk   = {iflnk(path)}
    ifsock  = {ifsock(path)}
    is_suid = {is_suid(path)}
    is_sgid = {is_sgid(path)}
    is_svtx = {is_svtx(path)}
    is_read = {is_read(path)}
    is_write = {is_write(path)}
    is_exec = {is_exec(path)}
    is_rwxu = {is_rwxu(path)}
    is_rusr = {is_rusr(path)}
    is_wusr = {is_wusr(path)}
    is_xusr = {is_xusr(path)}
    is_rwxg = {is_rwxg(path)}
    is_rgrp = {is_rgrp(path)}
    is_wgrp = {is_wgrp(path)}
    is_xgrp = {is_xgrp(path)}
    is_rwxo = {is_rwxo(path)}
    is_roth = {is_roth(path)}
    is_woth = {is_woth(path)}
    is_xoth = {is_xoth(path)}
    isExists      = {isExists(path)}
    isReadable    = {isReadable(path)}
    isWritable    = {isWritable(path)}
    isExecuteable = {isExecuteable(path)}
''')
```

Output:

```
    mode    = 511
    ifreg   = False
    ifdir   = True
    ifchr   = False
    ifblk   = False
    iffifo  = False
    iflnk   = False
    ifsock  = False
    is_suid = False
    is_sgid = False
    is_svtx = False
    is_read = True
    is_write = True
    is_exec = True
    is_rwxu = True
    is_rusr = True
    is_wusr = True
    is_xusr = True
    is_rwxg = True
    is_rgrp = True
    is_wgrp = True
    is_xgrp = True
    is_rwxo = True
    is_roth = True
    is_woth = True
    is_xoth = True
    isExists      = True
    isReadable    = True
    isWritable    = True
    isExecuteable = True
```

I would like to see Pure Python as an answer.

Comment: Don't have a windows machine at hand to test out, but comments on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233461/python-get-a-list-of-a-files-group-id-permissions-in-windows) might give you a starting point.

Comment: The python mantra is normally its better to ask forgiveness than ask for permission. I.E Instead of checking if you are allowed to do something. try to do it and just catch the exception. I.E wrap your code that might get an error due to permissions in a try block, then catch the exception, in the except block you can log the exception or set a variable to a default valur or print it or simply use `pass` if you want the program to do nothing when the exception occurs and just continue

Comment: @chrisDoyle yes, I think that would be the best way to go. Simply use a try/except statement to catch anything gone wrong with the permissions

Comment: Yes, I understand that try-except is better than checking access rights, but I have spent a lot of effort lately to figure this out, but I have not found a good option for myself. This is a purely academic question, I do not plan to use this in real code. I just wrote a wrapper for io and decided to try to implement this opportunity, it seemed to me that this might be useful to someone.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle At first I something was not right with winapi, but in the end I started to use it, and solved the problem. Thanks that found time for my question. I originally wanted to pull a dependence, but realized that in the case of Windows this is not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

the os module does have the os.access function to check access:

```
os.access('/path/to/folder', os.W_OK) # W_OK is for writing, R_OK for reading, etc.
```

Comment: The standard stat library and os.access() did not give me the desired results. There are also options with changing permissions for the directory, but this may not always work, especially in usermode, which is why I try to do the verification.